# How to calculate output shape in 3D convolution

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have a sequence of images of shape $(40,64,64,12)$. If I apply conv3d with 8 kernels having spatial extent $(3,3,3)$ without padding, how to calculate the shape of output.

If the next layer is max pooling with $(2,2,2)$, what will be the output shape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convolution formula is the same as in 2D and is well-described in [CS231n tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv):

$$Out = (W−F+2P)/S+1$$

... where $W$ is the input volume size, $F$ is the receptive field size, $S$ is the stride, and $P$ is the amount of zero padding used on the border. In particular, when $S=1$ and $P=0$, like in your question, it simplifies to

$$Out=W-F+1$$

So, if you input the tensor $(40,64,64,12)$, ignoring the batch size, and $F=3$, then the output tensor size will be $(38, 62, 62, 8)$.

---

Pooling layer normally halves each spatial dimension. This corresponds to the local receptive field size `F=(2, 2, 2)` and stride `S=(2, 2, 2)`. Hence, the input tensor $(38, 62, 62, 8)$ will be transformed to $(19, 31, 31, 8)$.

But you set the stride `S=(1, 1, 1)`, it'll reduce each spatial dimension by 1: $(37, 61, 61, 8)$.

The last dimension doesn't change.

Comment: shouldn't the last dimension be 10, instead of 8, going by the formula?

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in [PyTorch's documentation about `nn.Conv3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv3d)

[image]